# Laravel 4 caching mechanism implementation

Tags: php, caching, laravel, laravel-4

I wonder how safe it is to use Laravel 4 built-in DB query caching mechanism *($query->remember(10))*.

I can't find in the docs the implementation way, and, I wonder if it uses some kind of hashing algorithm of the **full DB query with all the binded (bonded??) values**, in order to set the cached item key (Which is safe enough for me :))

I also wonder if the implementation differs from one cache driver to another. I currently use the file system driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the source

```
#File: laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php
public function remember($minutes, $key = null)
{
    list($this->cacheMinutes, $this->cacheKey) = array($minutes, $key);

    return $this;
}
```

You can see the `remember` method uses a `cacheKey` object property.  This property is set in the `getCacheKey` method

```
#File: laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php
public function getCacheKey()
{
    return $this->cacheKey ?: $this->generateCacheKey();
}
```

Which uses the `generateCacheKey` method to create the cache key.

```
public function generateCacheKey()
{
    $name = $this->connection->getName();

    return md5($name.$this->toSql().serialize($this->getBindings()));
}
```

Here you can see that Laravel generates the cache key by using an `md5` hash of

1. The Connection Name
2. The SQL Query
3. A PHP serialized version of the data bindings (i.e. "all the binded (bonded??) values")

This key generation is independent of the cache engine used.